# displaying the square root of "X" in label

Tags: c#, math, label, square-root

I have written a simple calculator program in C# which can also calculate the square root of any number.

So, I was just wondering if you could display said number in a label. Or rather display it like you would when calculating in real maths where the number is under the square root

(https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51Vo0t5w5YL.jpg).

Is that even a possibility? For those curious:

```
//Root
if (CW3.Checked) //Square Root Box checked
{
    if (Z3N.Checked) //Negativ Number Box checked
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You can't get the square root of negative numbers.");
    }
    else
    {
        Zahl3 = Math.Sqrt(Zahl3);
    }
}
```

Comment: unless you want to render this your self, https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+221A

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it's just a small project, so perhaps you could use something like this:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Label Content="13.2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <Label Content="√" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="18" Margin="-11,-2,0,0"/>
    <Grid Height="1" Background="Black" Margin="3,-13,3,0"/>
</Grid>
```

Just copy it all and insert it instead of the label you have. And change the number - bind the content or edit from code behind or whatever you do. There might be some fidgeting with the margins, but that is all part of the fun. TextBlocks might be the way to go instead of labels though.